# If $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are independent random variables, are $XY$ and $ZY$ independent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, independence

I'm just wondering if we have random variables $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ if we take a function of $X$ and $Y$, namely, $g(X,Y)$ and a function of random variables $Y$ and $Z$, namely, $h(Y,Z)$ then are $g(X,Y)$ and $h(Y,Z)$ independent?

Comment: No. Obviously, you can take $g(x,y)=y$, $h(y,z)=y$.

Comment: Sorry how about if g(x,y)=XY and h(y,z)= YZ ? They are also dependent right?

Comment: Yes, since $\mathbb E[XY] = \mathbb E[X]\mathbb E[Y], \mathbb E[YZ] = \mathbb E[Y]\mathbb E[Z]$ and $\mathbb E[XY\cdot YZ] = \mathbb E[X]\mathbb E[Y^2]\mathbb E[Z]$, so that $Cov(XY,YZ) = \mathbb E[X]\mathbb E[Z] ( Var(Y) )$, so unless some of it is $0$, then you can't even get uncorellation, not to say about independence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not true. The intuitive reason is that $g(X,Y)$ can give us some information on $Y$, and so does $h(Y,Z)$, so they might easily end up sharing some information. The easiest case of this is $g(x,y)=y,h(y,z)=y$.

But even if $X,Y,Z$ are independent normal unit Gaussians, $h$ and $g$ are the sum of their arguments, $g(X,Y)$ and $h(Y,Z)$ have nonzero covariance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not always the case. You can take $g(X,Y)=Y$ and $h(Y,Z)=Y$, which implies they may be dependant.

Comment: @Mindlack had already given this answer.

Comment: @Ramanujan, Sorry hadn't seen that in the comments